# How to use sed text processing

Tags: linux, log-files, shell-scripting

> please i need your help on this topic.

**i have 3 temp files and nbf.txt.**

i want to copy each hour lines from this 3 temp files to nbf.txt:
inside each temp file we have
temp file for each hour:
**tmp1**
Receiveid Transaction
======================
2020-05-29 00->12

**tmp2**
Failed Transaction
===================
2020-05-29 00->1 failed

**temp3**

Failed Open Sessions Per Hour
==============================
2020-02-29 00->2 sessions

so i need to use sed for each temp file:

i am using the below command in my script:

```
sed -i -e '1,$p' nbf.txt -e '1,3d' tmp1
sed -i -e '1,$p' nbf.txt -e '1,3d' tmp2
sed -i -e '1,$p' nbf.txt -e '1,3d' tmp3
```

the result inside nbf.txt **NB:** 
*please i need the below result using **sed** or **tail** or **awk***

```
Received Transactions Per Hour
==============================
2020-02-29 00->69646 requests

2020-02-29 23->82666 requests

2361523 Received Transactions


Rejected Transactions Per Hour
===============================

0 Rejected Transactions


Failed Open Sessions Per Hour
==============================
2020-02-29 00->2 sessions
2020-02-29 22->1 sessions

8 Failed Sessions
```

but not working corrdctly

Comment: Could you add a couple of lines from one of the logs, as an example?

Comment: I don't get where the failed and rejected connections come from.

Answer (score 1):

In general there is no reason to pipe from `cat` to `grep` to `awk` and even to another `awk` because a single `awk` can do all that very well.

```
$ awk -F'[ :]' '/:/ { datestring=$1; a[$2]++;}; END { for(i=0;i<24;i++) '\
'{ ind=sprintf("%02d",i); '\
'printf "%s %2s->%7d\n",datestring,ind,(a[ind]>0) ? a[ind] : 0 ; }; }' \
Received_transaction.log-$Hour
2020-05-28 00->      0
2020-05-28 01->      0
2020-05-28 02->      0
2020-05-28 03->      0
2020-05-28 04->      0
2020-05-28 05->      0
2020-05-28 06->      0
2020-05-28 07->      0
2020-05-28 08->      0
2020-05-28 09->      0
2020-05-28 10->      0
2020-05-28 11->      0
2020-05-28 12->     13
2020-05-28 13->      0
2020-05-28 14->      0
2020-05-28 15->      0
2020-05-28 16->      0
2020-05-28 17->      0
2020-05-28 18->      0
2020-05-28 19->      0
2020-05-28 20->      0
2020-05-28 21->      0
2020-05-28 22->      0
2020-05-28 23->      0
```

Comment: `00:00 ====> 12:59` is 13 hours, not one. Due to race conditions there may be wrong entries in a file. Shall they be detected and ignored? Basically you are just counting the lines which contain a `:`, right?